# Website may have up to 10 files with same name/purpose, no version control

Tags: version-control, editor

I am new at working for a large company with various people working on the same files. Sadly we don’t have version control and I often find myself cross eyed.  For lack of better terminology, we have a dev site, quality-assurance site, and the live site. We have most files in two languages. Since the network connected drives have an average transfer rate of 15kb/sec we often copy the files locally before working on them.  Also contractors send us new versions of files, but we may have made changes on our side and everything gets screwed up.
Basically I’m working with 6-10 files with the same name and same purpose. Does anyone have any tips on how I can keep them straight? I use Beyond Compare 2 to see the differences but if there’s a program that compares all files time stamps to see which is most current may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suggest, take a lead and put your code in version control and push your team to move to new repository. It'll make everybody's life easier and most important reduce chances of any merge error.

Answer (score 2):

Thoughts:
1) Get version control system (Git), otherwise you will continue to have more and more pain.
2) Create a includes/lib folder and reduce that 6-10 files down (to 1).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you cannot convince the powers that be to actually use source code control, why not try using Mercurial purely locally.  Hopefully you can insulate yourself from some of the noise.  You could even make fake users for the contractors and commit & push those changes as though they were actually doing it.

It shouldn't be too hard to get a bureaucrat to see how nice a good gatekeeper like Mercurial or Git would be.  Its kind of like helpful red tape!